# Send CSRF token inside javascript POST gives an Error

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

In my web application I'm using spring security **3.2.x** and I'm doing CSRF validation. In my login page I have successfully done this. But inside, I have a button and the button action is written inside a javascript

```
        $('#download').click(function(){

            var paramValue = '${params}';
            var params = $('#params_').clone()
            $('<form target="_blank" action="report" method="post"></form>').append(params).appendTo('body').submit().remove();

        });
```

Now the problem is when I clicked on that button It gives the following error

> Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

I thinkthis is because It's **fail to send the CSRF token**. Can anybody tell me how to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I problem was in the following line I didn't send the csrf tokens like in the normal form submissions.

```
        $('<form target="_blank" action="report" method="post"></form>').append(params).appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

So what I did is I created the hidden field and insert it like bellow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#download').click(function(){                

            var params = $('#params_').clone();
            var csrftoken = $("#csrftoken_").clone();
            $('<form target="_blank" action="report" method="post"></form>')
                .append(params)
                .append(csrftoken)
                .appendTo('body')
                .submit()
                .remove();

        });
    });
</script>

  <input type='hidden' id='params_' name='params' value='${params}' />
  <input type="hidden" id="csrftoken_" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

This works....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you said it is because your dynamically created form does not contain valid CSRF token input. From [Spring Security documentation](http://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/):

```
$(function () {
  var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
  var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
  });
});
```

This will add required headers to your ajax requests.

Comment: do you see this header in your ajax request headers?

Comment: found the answer. Check the answer i gave

Comment: You are right. This is not an ajax request, not sure why I could not see.